# Should I highlight one of my old papers in my last 5 years research achievements, if the old paper got printed recently?

Tags: publications, journals, etiquette, cv, online-publication

It is general that most of the journals now a days publish article in online first and later give the volume and year name when they print it.

I have many papers in such case. However, I am confused to list them in recent publications. For example,

I had published 2 papers in 2012 which were in online until 2014. Then the print version came and I could see the volume name as xyz and year name as 2014.

Now I need to highlight my last five years publication in an academic form and that is also in online. As it is a mandatory case to provide volume name and year name, so my old papers are getting highlighted in my recent achievements.

I am wondering how the selection committee will look into  them?

In general which year should I write while listing those old papers in my CV?

Comment: What do you mean by _how the selection committee will look into them_?

Comment: @user2768 : I mean whether selection committee wold consider them (old papers initially published in online) as recent publications? If they do so, then those two will add to my recent publication list and hence increase my points, because more publications implies more points..

Comment: The selection committee know that journal publication takes time, hence, they know that journal articles represent older work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the instructions say otherwise, the "last five years" means the publication date that is written on the published paper is in the past five years.  It does not matter at all how long the paper was under review or in press.

A selection committee may see when the paper is submitted if that information is written on the paper, but they will not need that information.

Submission and revision dates are used when two papers come out from different authors which say the same thing.  Then the dates can indicate who is first.  I wouldn't worry too much about being first, though.

Answer (score 1):

> which year should I write while listing those old papers in my CV?

*Publication year* must be listed (your CV is no different to a bibliography, in this respect), you could additionally list *submitted in XXXX*, but this isn't necessary.

One way to distinguish old papers from new papers is to refer to papers in the body of your CV, e.g.,

```
 2017-Present, Position 1, University A, Country A

    Describe new research [1,2].

 2014-2017, Position 2, University B, Country Y

    Describe old research [3,4].
```